# Printf statments not printing in order

Tags: c

```
typedef struct node_s{
int data;         
struct node_s *next;
}node_t;                

void insert(node_t *pointer, int data){
     while(pointer->next != NULL){     
           pointer = pointer->next;     
     }                                 
     pointer->next = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
     pointer       = pointer->next;                   
     pointer->data = data;                            
     printf("Elemnet inserted\n"); //2. Followed by this statment once done.                      
     pointer->next = NULL;                            
}
int main(){                        
    node_t *start, *temp;          
    start      = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    temp       = start;                           
    temp->next = NULL;                            
    printf("1. Insert\n");
    printf("2. Delete\n");
    printf("3. Print\n");
    printf("4. Find\n");

    while(1){
     int input;
     scanf("%d\n", &input);

     if(input==1){
        int data;
        printf("Input data\n");//1. I want this to print out first once I give 1 input.
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d", &data);
        insert(start, data);
     }
    }
```

When I compile and execute, I can give inputs but the order of printf statements are not in sequence. For instance, this is how I get the output after I give input and enter the data.

```
sh-4.1$ ./linked_list
1. Insert
2. Delete
3. Print
4. Find
1
23
Input data
Elemnet inserted
1
45
Input data
Elemnet inserted
```

I tried adding fflush(stdout), after the printf statment as well.

Comment: Where is your printing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `\n` from the very first `scanf`

```
scanf("%d\n", &input);
```

What is that `\n` doing there? That is what is causing your `scanf` to "linger", waiting for extra input, instead of terminating immediately.

That `\n` has special meaning for `scanf`. When you use a whitespace character (space, tab or `\n`) in `scanf` format specifier, you are explicitly asking `scanf` to skip all whitespace. If such character is used at the very end of `scanf` format string, then after reading the actual data `scanf` will continue to wait for input until it encounters a non-whitespace character. This is exactly what happens in your case.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to removing `\n` from your `scanf` statements, be aware that `scanf` will read the data from the command line, filling the variable specified, **but it will leave the `\n` in the input buffer** causing problems the next time `scanf` is called. Since there is no standard command to flush input buffers, you are responsible for insuring that you do not have extraneous unused characters in the input buffer the next time `scanf` is called. One simple way to handle manually flushing the input buffer after each `scanf` if to simply use `getchar()` to read any remaining characters in the input buffer until `\n` is encountered. For example:

```
int c;
...
scanf ("format", &var);
do {
    c = getchar();
while ( c != '\n' );
```

This will insure subsequent calls to `scanf` retrieves the wanted data instead of passing the characters that remain in the input buffer.

Comment: Not sure what problems your are referring to. Almost all format specifiers of `scanf` automatically skip all whitespace before reading actual data. Fort this reason, whatever whitespace is left over in the input buffer does not cause any problems at all. It will be skipped automatically by the next `scanf`. The only exception from this behavior is format specifiers like `%c`, which don't skip. But this can be easily fixed  by explicitly asking `scanf` to skip whitespace.

Comment: Problems might arise when one's mixing different input methods, like `scanf` and `getchar`. But programs that use `scanf` exclusively are typically completely insensitive to any problems from any whitespace left in the buffer.

Comment: Grr.. You are correct as usual sir -- fixed :) Why is there no warning generated when c is defined as char instead of int? E.g. with `char c` and `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-long-long -o bin/gc getchar.c` no warning? I agree with you though, `man 3 getchar` it is an int.

Comment: @AndreyT when there are successive calls to `scanf`, as here, any stray input included, and the `\n` itself, can cause problems at the following `scanf` call. Flushing stdin following `scanf` is on par with insuring you initialize all variables, it's just good practice and prevents issues later. I didn't mean to step on your toes, but was simply providing additional safeguards related to the exact call at issue.

Comment: @David C. Rankin: Sorry, I don't see it. The point is that non-whitespace stray input can indeed cause problems, but *whitespace* stray input (including `\n`) cannot cause any problems. Again: `scanf` automatically skips all whitespace, stray or not. There's no need to flush whitespace from input when you are using `scanf`. And if you really want to flush it for `scanf` for some reason, a better idea would be to do it using built-in features of `scanf` itself instead of building-up any cycles with `getchar`.

Comment: @David C. Rankin: Anyway, if you can provide an example where stray whitespace creates problems for `scanf` - I'm all ears.